# Hibernate Search : IllegalArgumentException while indexing a child class @Field using @IndexedEmbedded

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I encountered an `IllegalArgumentException` while indexing a new record in the commit phase of my Hibernate transaction.

I have the following configuration :

```
@Indexed(index = "quotation")
@Entity
@Table(name = "quotation")
public class QuotationEntity {

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quotation", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<QuotationLineEntity> quotationLines = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "quotation_line")
public abstract class QuotationLineEntity {
}

@Indexed(index = "quotation_article")
@Entity
@Table(name = "quotation_article")
public class QuotationArcticleEntity extends QuotationLineEntity {

    @Field
    @Column(name = "designation")
    private String designation;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "quotation_item")
public class QuotationItemEntity extends QuotationLineEntity {
}
```

Let's imagine that I created the following object : a quotation with 2 quotationLines :

- QuotationArticleEntity (designation = "test")
- QuotationItemEntity (designation field is not present)

While indexing, I get the following stack :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not get property value
    at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.ReflectionHelper.getMemberValue(ReflectionHelper.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFieldsForProperties(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFieldsForEmbeddedObjects(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.getDocument(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.createAddWork(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.addWorkToQueue(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerEntityWork.enqueueLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerClassWork.enqueueLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan.getPlannedLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.WorkQueue.prepareWorkPlan(WorkQueue.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.prepareWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.beforeCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$BeforeCommitSynchronizationDelegator.beforeCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.internal.SynchronizationRegistryStandardImpl.notifySynchronizationsBeforeTransactionCompletion(SynchronizationRegistryStandardImpl.java:60)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoking designation with wrong parameters
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXProperty.invoke(JavaXProperty.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXProperty.invoke(JavaXProperty.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.ReflectionHelper.getMemberValue(ReflectionHelper.java:90)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field entity.QuotationArticleEntity.designation to entity.QuotationItemEntity
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXProperty.invoke(JavaXProperty.java:80)
    ... 101 more
```

What I can see is that the Hibernate Search's `DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFieldsForProperties()` tries to access the members of **each** collected meta data on all the child classes (through `typeMetadata.getAllPropertyMetadata()`) on **all** the child classes, this is why the QuotationArticleEntity.designation can't be applied to QuotationItemEntity.

**Remarks :**

- using @IndexedEmbedded(targetElement = QuotationArticleEntity.class) did not solve the problem
- I experienced the problem on Hibernate Search 5.5.2. The 5.5.10 version does not seem to be modified to solve this issue

Is there any way to fix this or is this a Hibernate seach issue?

Kind regards

Comment: Looks like a bug, but I [wasn't able to reproduce it](https://github.com/yrodiere/hibernate-test-case-templates/commits/stackoverflow_53207433). You should consider upgrading to at least 5.6, the oldest maintained version, where we solved quite a few bugs compared to 5.5. If the problem is still there, you can report it on our [JIRA tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH/), preferably with a test case based on our [test case templates](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-lucene) and we will fix it (on 5.6 and later).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the attempts to reproduce. I updated to the versions you mentioned but the problem persists. I will try to investigate more on the differences of your example and mine, and come back to you with newer elements. I keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

Here is useful link :

- https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

Okey could you try

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
```

If you want to use

```
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

Try to use some id in your abstract class and in every sublclass use

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, the abstract class is already annotated with this strategy. I did not mention it in my summarized example. I modify the post to mention it. Or should I add it somewhere else?

Comment: Updated answer please take a look)

Comment: Thank you for the update. I will try to see if this can solve the problem. KR.

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: Well, sorry, I never had chance to rework this, then left the project :/